# Implementing Tree Structure in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, treeview

I want to implement a tree structure in a `UITableView` something like

```
 Item-1
     subItem-1
     subItem-2
 Item-2
 Item-3
     subItem-1
     subItem-2
```

but I don't want to use custom cells for this.
I have done lot of `Googling` for this but I got one link which said I would have to use custom cells.

If anyone has any ideas please can you shared them with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi Khushbu dwnlod this example @https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView  OR:- also dwnlode this one developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: `github` link is good. But i am looking for a code that has nested tree. Child inside a child. I found https://github.com/seletz/CocoaTreeViewExample very good sample but not able to make is section wise so far :(

Answer (score 1):

A table view isn't really designed to display hierarchical views. What's supposed to happen is that you drill down (push a new view controller on the stack) to get to the next level of the hierarchy.

However, if your hierarchy is only as deep as you suggest, then you could have your items as headers and subitems as rows. If you don't want to create a custom view (why not?) you'd be limited to just text for your top level items.

Comment: :you are right and also thought about it but my requirement is if item-2 doesn't have any subitem and I click on item-2 then result of item-2 should be displayed in detailview. then how can I arrange such kind of situation?